# Converting from Mathematical script to normal script

Tags: php

In one of our applications that is connected to facebook leads, we are getting some strange first names and last names. After some googling, I found that for some reason some people are writing their name using Mathematical Script, for example: ```````

For example the big L: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2112

Is there any way I can convert this to normal script? Without doing an comparison table?

This is a completely valid char, and we are showing them correctly due to using all mb_* string functions, so it doesn't affect the functionality. It's more a question of appearance than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Normalizer class in PHP to achieve this. Here's a simple example of how you can normalize the text:

```
<?php
$originalName = '';
$normalized = Normalizer::normalize($originalName, Normalizer::FORM_C);

echo $normalized; // Output: Laurette

?>
```

This will normalize the string `$originalName` into its canonical decomposition, which should convert the mathematical script characters into their regular script equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php)

```
Normalizer::normalize('', Normalizer::FORM_KD);
```